# Batch rename files to lowercase

Tags: command-line, rename, batch-rename

Is there a way to rename *all files* in a directory to lowercase|uppercase?

I am looking for a *oneliner* command.

I loved TotalCommander's <kbd>Alt + F7</kbd>, now I need that functionality in the Terminal.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For each file `a_file` in current directory rename `a_file` to lower case.

```
for a_file in *;do mv -v "$a_file" `echo "$a_file" | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]` ;done;
```

For upper case reverse the arguments to `[:lower:] [:upper:]`

`tr` command reference [link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/9base-tr.1.html)

**Update**

For even more control `*` can be replaced with `ls`.

For example in a directory containing 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, 1.jpg, 2.jpg and 3.jpg in order to filter only *.jpg files, `ls` can be used:

```
for a_file in $(ls *.jpg);do mv -v $a_file `echo $a_file | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]` ;done;
```

The above code will assign to `a_file` variable all files with .jpg extension.

**Update** added `-v` option to `mv` command as per [sds](https://askubuntu.com/users/80483/sds) suggested.

Comment: you might want to pass "-v" to `mv` so that you see what is being done; you might _not_ want to pass "-f" because this may clobber existing files

Comment: This does not work for files with spaces in their name.

Comment: You can use quotes around the filename.

Comment: Sorry, but the part about ls *jpg is a **bad** idea.  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs    You can achive the same result with *jpg along where you had * in the first place.

Answer (score 17):

There's a more elegant and general utility called `prename`.

Written by Larry Wall, it comes with `perl` so it is most likely already available on your system as `/usr/bin/prename` (if you have setup alternatives is may also be available as `/usr/bin/rename` symlinked via /etc/alternatives to `prename`)

Using it you can rename multiple files in one command by providing any perl expression (including but not limited to substitution `s///` or char transliteration `tr///`):

**Examples:**

```
# Lowercase all *.JPG filenames:
prename tr/A-Z/a-z/ *.JPG

# Change any 'No' in a filename to a 'Yes':
prename s/No/Yes/g *No*

# increment first sequence of digits in a filename by 3:
prename 's/([0-9]+)/$1+3/e' *[0-9]*

# If a file contains 'aaa', append '.bak' to its name
prename 'if (/aaa/) {$_ .= ".bak"}'  *
```

And so on.

Another nice thing about prename is that it protects you, in the case of renaming a file to an existing file name.

`man prename` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

## Using `find`

```
find . -name * -type f -exec rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' '{}' \;
```

### For `find`

- Of course after `-name` put your pattern.
- `-maxdepth 0`: Only current directory.

### For `rename`

- `-n, -nono`: No action: print names of files to be renamed, but don't rename.
- `y/source/dest/`: Transliterate the characters in the pattern space which appear in source to the corresponding character in dest.

Answer (score 0):

Using `mmv` to convert matched string to uppercase:

```
$ mmv -r '*' '#u1'
```

<sup>Its important to quote the pattern otherwise it will expand the wildcard instead.</sup>