# Rename all files in a folder from camel case to lowercase and put underscore to separate words

Tags: rename

I have a bunch of files like `FileNameX.cpp` and I would like to rename all of them to their respective `file_name_x.cpp`.

Comment: does [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/283425/51428) answer work for you?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This bash command do the job. From the command line, enter the folder, and run this line:

```
for file in ./* ; do mv "$file" "$(echo $file|sed -e 's/\([A-Z]\)/_\L\1/g' -e 's/^.\/_//')" ; done
```

In script form it looks like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for file in ./* ; do
    mv "$file" "$(echo $file|sed -e 's/\([A-Z]\)/_\L\1/g' -e 's/^.\/_//')"
done
```

Basically `sed` is used to manipulate strings. There're two **e**xpressions:

1. `s/\([A-Z]\)/_\L\1/g`: searches for capitals to **s**ubstitutes them for lower case and add the underscore
2. `s/^.\/_//`: removes any underscore which was inserted due to the first letter being a capital (i.e. you don't want `_file_name_x.cpp`.

Consider using `-v`, `--verbose` on mv to explain what is being done.

Comment: There's a single quote missing after the first ```-e```